# How to find where an image is called React

Tags: reactjs

there is a svg logo file that i'm working with and the issue is that I want to find where in the entire react app are the instances where the svg logo file is called. Is there a way to do this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3Jm.jpg)

I've tried finding the direct file path of the svg image

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot easier if you are using vs code.
You can do Edit, Find in Files (or `Ctrl+Shift+F` )
default key binding, `Cmd+Shift+F` on MacOS) to search the Currently open Folder.